# Default selected checkbox

Tags: html, angular

I want to ask about how I can set option to be default selected?

```
<form [formGroup]="form2">
  <select formControlName="drop">
    <option disabled>Choose one</option>
    <option *ngFor="let example of examples" [value]="example.id" [disabled]="example.isDisabled" [selected]="example.isSelected">{{ example.name }}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-drop-down-list',
  templateUrl: './drop-down-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drop-down-list.component.css']
})
export class DropDownListComponent implements OnInit {

  public form = new FormGroup({
    drop: new FormControl('',
      Validators.required,
    ),
  });

  public form2 = new FormGroup({
    drop: new FormControl('',
      Validators.required,
    ),
  });

  examples = [{
    id: 1, name: 'Test1', isSelected: false, isDisabled: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2, name: 'Test2', isSelected: true, isDisabled: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3, name: 'Test3', isDisabled: false,
  }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form);
  }

}
```

I was searching on stack but I don't want to mix reactive forms with ngModel, also I don't wan't to use patchValue because It only set default value without choosing element in list. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want option to be selected then do like this , just pass id value in your formcontrol intialization

```
  public form2 = new FormGroup({
    drop: new FormControl(this.examples[0].id,
      Validators.required,
    ),
  });
```

or if you dont want to initialization immediately and want later on then make use of setValue method, below is required when you are fecthing data from server and want to set value i just hard coded value just to show as example , you should replace with the value you get from server

```
form2.get('drop').setValue('1');
```

---

html should be as below no need of `[selected]`

```
 <select formControlName="drop">
    <option disabled>Choose one</option>
    <option *ngFor="let example of examples" [value]="example.id" [disabled]="example.isDisabled" >{{ example.name }}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: I would have gone for `new FormControl(this.examples[0].id,
      Validators.required)` but otherwise I agree

Comment: @trichetriche - ok lets do the change , updated answer

Comment: Thanks! I have only one more question, we're I can find list of attributes that doesn't work normal with angular?

Comment: @Gnex - normally html attributes not work with anuglar , for example tooltip on textbox or